# How to access private SharedPref.java method?

Tags: java, android

My `SharedPref.java` is as follows:

```java
public class SharedPref  {

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "Wallet";

    private static SharedPref instance;

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public static SharedPref getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        instance = new SharedPref(context);
    }

    private SharedPref(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void saveOAuthResponse(OAuthTokensResponse response) {
        preferences.edit()
                .putString("access", response.getAccessToken())
                .apply();
        preferences.edit()
                .putString("refresh", response.getRefreshToken())
                .apply();
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return preferences.getString("access", null);
    }

    public String getRefreshToken() {
        return preferences.getString("refresh", null);
    }

    public void clearTokens() {
        preferences.edit()
                .putString("access", null)
                .apply();
        preferences.edit()
                .putString("refresh", null)
                .apply();
    }
}
```

I am trying to access it through an activity with this line of code:

```java
String token = SharedPref.getInstance().getAccessToken();
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.coin.coinsway.SharedPref.getAccessToken()' on a null object reference

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could it be that you want to create a singleton? If so, then you should add a line of code to `getInstance()` Method: `if (instance == null) instance = new SharedPref();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPref.instance is null, because it hasn't been initialised.
You can initialise it in your MainActivity's onCreate method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    SharedPref.init(this);
    // ...
}
```

(In case you want to access SharedPref.getInstance() in onCreate, make sure you initialise it before trying to access it)

Answer (score 0):

The static method `init` probably hasn't been called, since `getInstance()` returns `null`

Comment: so what do you suggest I do?

Comment: You need to call `init` with some `Context` object in order to initialise the class.

Comment: may you give me an example please

Comment: I can't be more specific, because I don't know anything about the other classes, like `Context`

Comment: I just want to access the value from it through button click, so I actually do not have much code. If you can give some line of example code I would grasp the idea

Comment: Like @ole mentioned you need to call init method. You need to check if your project is based out of spring (xml), refer to context bean and add it SharedPref bean. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401090/spring-init-method-params and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432223/spring-init-method-with-parameters-issue

Comment: `Context context = new Context(); // probably wrong
SharedPref.init(context);
String token = SharedPref.getInstance().getAccessToken();`